# global name chat_id is not defined

Tags: python, bots, telepot

I'm trying to send a message after a user has clicked on the inline buttons. It tells me the chat_id is not valid. When i take it out it tells me i have to include it.

Every other button works fine and i recieve the callback in terminal

```
def on_callback_query(msg):
    query_id, from_id, query_data = telepot.glance(msg, flavor='callback_query')
    print('Callback Query:', query_id, from_id, query_data)
    
    if query_data == 'a':
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id, 'dsuhsdd')
```

Comment: Is the chat_id a global variable? The context of the snippet you posted does not include where the chat_id is comming from.

Comment: The error is that the global name is not defined

Comment: Python would not allow you use a variable without throwing a **reference error**. You have to check your source code (do a find with your code editor) to see where the variable **chat_id** is defined. It's probably an empty string or a nonsensical value.

Comment: I'll have to open a new question when i get a chance

Answer (score 0):

Good, I see the problem,
First get an authorization token >> https://telepot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#get-a-token

Next, add this to get the chat_id

```
content_type, chat_type, chat_id = telepot.glance(msg)
```

You were using **query_data** as a reference to **chat_id**

Comment: Where exactly should i add that? I already have a token

Comment: your answer is out-of-contest, because is for glancing messages and not query

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to comlicate your life with global scoping, because in your `on_callback_query` function you `glanced` the query so you retrieved 3 var:

```
query_id, from_id, query_data = telepot.glance(msg)
```

so you only need to use `from_id` that represents the `chat_id` that sended the query, so:

```
def on_callback_query(msg):
    query_id, from_id, query_data = telepot.glance(msg, flavor='callback_query')
    print('Callback Query:', query_id, from_id, query_data)
    
    if query_data == 'a':
        bot.sendMessage(from_id, 'dsuhsdd')
```

when you glance a message you have:

```
content_type, chat_type, chat_id = telepot.glance(msg)
#type of mesg, type of chat, chat identifier
```

but when you glance a callback query:

```
query_id, from_id, query_data = telepot.glance(msg)
#query id, chat_id, txt data related to the query
```